Is the Kubernetes documentation's example for NetworkPolicy wrong
This is the example NetworkPolicy from the Kubernetes documentation here (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/):
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: test-network-policy
  namespace: default
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      role: db
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
  ingress:
  - from:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 172.17.0.0/16
        except:
        - 172.17.1.0/24
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          project: myproject
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          role: frontend
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 6379
  egress:
  - to:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 10.0.0.0/24
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5978

The problem is when I used this as a template to make an egress NetworkPolicy as seen below (this was for a example scenario on KillerCoda's "NetworkPolicy Namespace Selector" scenario):
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: np
  namespace: space1
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
  egress:
  - to:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          kubernetes.io/metadata.name: space2
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 53
    - protocol: UDP
      port: 53

This was able to be successfully created by Kubernetes, but I wasn't able to pass the check to successfully run this command

k -n space1 exec app1-0 -- curl -m 1
microservice1.space2.svc.cluster.local

The reason it failed was because the ports that were set to allow outgoing DNS traffic weren't actually being set. The reason being is because, as you see in the example solution from the site below. The "ports:" needs to be "- ports:" and lined up with the "-to":
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: np
  namespace: space1
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
  egress:
  - to:
     - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
         kubernetes.io/metadata.name: space2
  - ports:
    - port: 53
      protocol: TCP
    - port: 53
      protocol: UDP

When I made that change it worked successfully.
I don't know why the documentation doesn't show ports with the "- " in its example. So is the Kubernetes documentation's example wrong and should be changed or what am I missing?

Putting '-' in front of both 'to' and 'ports' effectively separate them into two elements under 'egress' with one only has 'to' key while the other only has 'ports' key, whereas the original config with only one '-' in front of 'to' while 'ports' has no '-' means both 'to' and 'ports' belong to the same element of 'egress'.

Or translated into JSON, the original was {"egress": [{"to": ... , "ports": ... }]} while yours is {"egress": [{"to": ... }, {"ports": ... }]}

Your final YAML configuration creates two independent egress rules. Basically, your first rule allows traffic to all ports to pods in namespace space2. The second rule allows TCP and UDP traffic on port 53 to any namespaces  since it is not part of any “- to:” selector.
Try to stick with the template provided by the documentation, so that you could create only one egress rule wherein all traffic coming from space1 to all pods of space2 are allowed, while associating port restriction destined to pods in space2. Also, you need to include “- ipBlock:” with the ip ranges of pods in space2 to your configuration, just make sure it is also part of “- to:” selector.
